# Tflearn/Tensorflow value error: "Cannot feed value of shape (50, 11, 11) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm totally new to NN and tflearn, and recently I'm writing a python program which can play Gomoku game. I want to use lots of games to train my network. This is input(train_state), a list of many 4* 11* 11 numpy arrays which discribes current state:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

   [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]])
```

and trian_nextmove is a list of many 11* 11 arrays like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

I found that even use the simplest network, it got wrong.
the code is here:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
g=tflearn.input_data(shape=[None,4,11,11],name='input')

g=tflearn.fully_connected(g,128,activation='relu',name="hidden1")
g=tflearn.fully_connected(g,64,activation='relu',name="hidden2")
g=tflearn.fully_connected(g,1,activation='softmax',name="output")
g=tflearn.regression(g,optimizer='adam',learning_rate=0.1,metric='R2',loss='categorical_crossentropy')

m=tflearn.DNN(g)
m.fit(train_state,train_nextmove,n_epoch=10,batch_size=50,snapshot_epoch=False,shuffle=True)

x0=train_state[34]
pred0=m.predict(x0)
```

print(pred0)
print("Saving the model")
g.save('g.tflearn')

Comment: I'm not using tflearn but it seems that your last layer is a dense layer composed of one neuron, that would make your output shape `(1,)` but you passed targets with shape `(11, 11)` in your `fit` function

Comment: Thank you very much! I have solved it by reshape my trian_nextmove to output shape(121) and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Proving the solution in the answer section even if the answer is present in the comments for the benefit of the community.

The issue was with the shape of `trian_nextmove`, reshaping the trian_nextmove of `shape (11,11)` to output shape `(121)` resolved the issue.